# Display zero if null

Tags: vba, ms-access, null, zero

I have some VBA code on a form which performs a look up of the total number of errors from a query.

```
Private Sub cboProjectID_Change() 
   Dim VarTotalErrors As Variant 
   VarTotalErrors = DLookup("[total errors]", "[Project_Total_Errors_Query]", "[Project_ID] = " & VarComboKey) 
   Me.txttotalerrors = VarTotalErrors 
End Sub
```

What condition would I need to add to this VBA code to automatically populate a value of zero when the total_errors is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can feed the `DLookup` value to `Nz` and assign that result to the text box directly, which simplifies the code.

```
Private Sub cboProjectID_Change()
    Me.txttotalerrors = Nz(DLookup("[total errors]", _
        "[Project_Total_Errors_Query]", _
        "[Project_ID] = " & VarComboKey), 0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub cboProjectID_Change() 
   Dim VarTotalErrors As Variant 
   VarTotalErrors = DLookup("[total errors]", "[Project_Total_Errors_Query]", "[Project_ID] = " & VarComboKey) 
   If Nz(VarTotalErrors) = 0 Then
       Me.txttotalerrors = "0" 
   else
       Me.txttotalerrors = VarTotalErrors 
   end if
End Sub
```